# W10 prevents Linux access

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I am a Linux user - very basic techie..Been using Linux for 16 years.   Installed Linux alongside Windows 10 on a new Acer Aspire c24-865.
PC boots straight in Windows ....
Since I cannot access UEFI in this BIOS (version R02-A0),
none of the solutions   I have seen so far seem to apply ..
Thanks for your help!!!  I tried all other solutions such as this:
Windows 10 Boots Automatically After Installing Ubuntu

Comment: Boot with your Live USB and install `boot-repair` to it. Run boot repair and it should set it up to boot to grub where you can select either Windows 10 or Ubuntu from a menu. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Tried that with no success... I feel the problem is related to the Acer Bios ... even with a supervisor PW set and secured boot off, I don't get any UEFI options .. cannot change the boot order.. Had I known wouls never had bought this Acer machine

Comment: Thanks for your answer... tried that  - boot-repair went fine but nothing changed regarding UEFI's sequence... The ACER docum regarding management of UEFI does not apply either to this computer (new model)..

Comment: If you do not have settings in UEFI, you need to update UEFI from Acer. Some old threads mention downgrading, but many newer threads say UEFI update from Acer then offers the option to set "trust" on ubuntu boot entries. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298380

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on my Aspire C24-865.
Tried boot-repair, with same results although noticed that the error report said 'try the following in Win10'

1. Run Command.com as Admin.
2. Enter following instruction:

   ```
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
   ```
3. Re-start computer.

That worked for me. Grub menu now loads to give the expected OS choices.

Comment: Thanks all - Boot-repair dis not work and gave me some error message with the suggestion to bcdedit  in Windows which did work - I got Ubuntu to appear in dual-boot . I had reverted to Ubuntu as Linuxmint did not work. Any simpleway to head back - uninstall Ubuntu and go on to install Linuxmint which I definitly prefer

Comment: Thanks all - one last comment... From my experience do not use VisualBcdedit with W10 - once Visual opens the bcdstore, it is impossible to use, as an example, the following: bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi. Will go back to w10 with re-install and start-over... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Accessing UEFI from Windows 10 on an Acer can be a bit convoluted. If the links provided by my peers in [their](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097701/w10-prevents-linux-access#comment1821765_1097701) [comments](https://askubuntu.com/q/1097701/#comment1821768_1097701)  don't resolve your issue, and you can't access the UEFI settings by hitting F2 or Del when the logo screen appears at power on, boot into Windows 10 and then

- Click the Start Start menu and select Settings..
- Click Update & security.
- Click Update and recovery.
- Select Recovery from the left column, then
- Click Restart now.
- Once boot menu appears, select Troubleshoot.
- In Troubleshoot menu, select Advanced options.
- In Advanced options menu, click UEFI Firmware Settings.
- Click Restart. The system will restart and enter UEFI (BIOS).

Source: https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27103/

Comment: Thanks EG - I can get into BIOS directly at boot time but the UEFI sequence cannot be changed directly there on this Acer Aspire c24-865 (supervisor PW on, etc..). Original try was with Linuxmint but I did revert to Ubuntu as solutions were Ubuntu based. Now that I know it can be done, any simple way to unistal Ubuntu + dual-boot and proceed with Linuxmint which is really my prefered Linux flavor

Comment: @RayGiguere questions regarding Linux mint are on topic at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ I suggest you ask there as MInt is off-topic here. It sounds like you have a buggy implementaion of UEFI. As you have the latest version of the BIOS I would recommend that you discuss your issues with changing the boot sequence with [Acer support](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/service-contact)

Comment: Thanks - will do that. One last comment here : I think the culprit may be BCDEDIT Visual ....  I did change the UEFI order using bcdedit set path command to get Ubuntu working prior to using VISUAL BCD to try to work my way back and install Mint.. did not work and once Visual BCD opens the bcd store, I cannot use bcdedit edit set path command anymore - get this strange message  bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efiThe set command specified is not valid.
                Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
                The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: @RayGiguere as it appears that you now have a question regarding Windows 10 (which bcdedit is a component of), I would be remiss if I didn't mention our sister site @ superuser.com. In fact you might find this interesting:  https://superuser.com/questions/693715/what-is-the-equivalent-command-for-bcdboot-in-bcdedit

Comment: Thanks so much EG!  I am getting closer now... did get LinuxMint to dual boot finally - only problem left is I have only read access to W10 NTFS drive in Linux while previously under W7, I had full  RW access. This was usefull to leave all documentsin NTFS with double access.

Comment: Forgot to mention : BCDEDIT problem stemmed in part because I was using it under POWERSHELL in adm. mode  I found somewhere in this forum someone using instead the CMD in Admin mode - that worked! Regarding the point above  on NTFS access - should I open another questions and close this one? This is my first interaction with the forum so...

Comment: @RayGiguere As your questions appear to have morphed considerably since you originally asked and no longer appear to have any relationship to Ubuntu, You should A) Leave this question open as it's already acting as a signpost to point people in the right direction AND B) open a new question on either https://unix.stackexchange.com/ (where Mint is on topic) or https://superuser.com/ where Windows is well supported. Best of luck. Cheers!